# Export oracle database with VB.net

Tags: database, vb.net, export, oracle12c

**Situation:**

- Oracle client 12c is installed on a remote server, not on local machine.
- Application is running on a local machine that have direct access to the database, not to the server

**Question:**

Is there a library available for exporting oracle database 12c?

I do not have access to expdp/rman etc on the local machine. Preferably not to connect to server because it requires a different set of username and password.

Comment: why you don't have access to expdp or exp? They can be installed on the client.

Comment: Hi Steve, I've updated my question. I'm trying to figure out a way that allows me to create oracle backup/export directly from the connection to the database. And installing another oracle database on the local machine would go against my original intention.